# Responsive tool for showing me the current browser size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, breakpoints

I am looking for a **tool** out there with which I can determine the **current browser size** to find out the **breakpoints** for **responsive design**...

And an other question i´m interesting in is... 
how do you deal with those issues to find your breakpoints doing responive design in HTML/CSS?

Comment: did you google?

Comment: yes, of course... i did find some, but there are not that what i expected.
So i would like to know how you deal with it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll explain this as basic as posible:
If you use Google Chrome and right click on the page, you get the option "Inspect element". If you select this you'll get an extra window with all the elements (DOM-view). on the top right of this 'inspector' there are 3 dots, click on this and select one of the options that isn't the overlay-looking option (undock). When you select one of these 3 options the inspector will be stuck to the page. Put your mouse on the edge of the inspector where it meets the page so that you can resize the inspector. If you resize it, you'll see in the top-right corner the exact dimensions of the  page **without** the inspector.
Another option is to select the mobile/tablet-looking icon on the top-left corner of the inspector. This will show you the page in "device-mode". if you select "Responsive" in the dropdown menu, you can then specify the exact dimensions of the page.